# Not able to run any command in startup task in windows Node

Tags: azure-batch

I have a very simple startup task commandline
"cmd /c echo Hello world from the Batch Hello world sample!"

it keeps on running into error , what am i doing wrong ?
I am using MicrosoftWindowsServer WindowsServer 2016-Datacenter-smalldisk (latest) image for my windows

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have quoted the entire CommandLine. Instead, you should quote the command portion only:

```
 cmd.exe /c "echo Hello world from the Batch Hello world sample!"
```